# Why is there a German flag on Yondu’s pillow?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* in the last scenes: Why does the pillow under Yondu's head have a German flag on it?

[image: Close up of Yondu’s face on his funeral pyre with a red circle showing what looks to be a German flag his head is resting on]

The colors in my TV are definitely black, not dark blue:

[image: Close up of the flag under Yondu’s head showing the colour is indeed black not blue]

About the point from the comments:

It is black- red - yellow, no dark blue (see the picture above)

It is not the Belgian flag (black - yellow - red)

If it is turned around (yellow - red - black) it no longer be a flag of any country (there seems to be only one flag with this order of a district in Czech Republic).

The allover size is not like a real functional flag. But a scarf with black - red - yellow on a sports event would also be a connection to Germany...

Comment: @Allerleirauh - You might want to note that he's surrounded by crap that he's picked up on a hundred worlds, including a [Danish troll doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_doll)

Comment: @Valorum thank you for the picture. The troll and other trash as far as I could see is with connection to USA or other famous stuff. And there are no other flags (I have noticed)I assumed some "greetings" or homage in any way but I could not imagine more details... and then I ask :)

Comment: certain it's a german flag? Could be a dark blue instead of black, and the shape seems to be wrong for the stripes to be oriented in that position. Also of note is that is funeral coverings seem to be red followed by yellow on his face as well

Comment: Are we sure these aren't things the other raiders donated?

Comment: @NKCampbell I have seen the movie yesterday and it was black instead of dark blue. What do you mean with "orientation"? If you "look him in his face" the color order is the same as the German flag.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage no one knows until someone find a source or well reasoned hypothesis, like "one of the raider ships has this and this, which seems to make the connection to the flag"

Comment: It can also be Belgian flag, just tiled on a wrong side.

Comment: @Oni Actually no, as the Belgian Flag is Black-Yellow-Red: [Flag of Belgium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Belgium), colors of the Duché de Brabant, whereas the [Flag of Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Germany) (or the Flag of the Weimar Republic) is Black-Red-Yellow (not the same Red & Yellows though)

Comment: @Oni they only had to turn it around and it would be no flag of a country anymore...

Comment: Another thought that I couldn't quite reach, is this a sly reference to David Hasselhoff?

Comment: He's also got a US Army 'Good Conduct' ribbon; https://media.defense.gov/2016/Dec/19/2001680731/2000/2000/0/161215-F-YG475-529.JPG

Answer (score 2):

This is highly unlikely to be a German flag. Firstly, it is too small for a normal sized flag so unless it is a cushion cover with the flag markings on it, it is unlikely to be one. Also from the image supplied, and I can't find a better one or different angle really, the yellow stripe is bigger than the other two. This leads me to believe it is not the flag and is just "some Ravager stuff" as part of the colourful funeral. Note the bands/ribbons across his face are also yellow and red and his body has some similar ones.

[image: Top view of Yondu lying on his funeral bed surrounded by flowers and candles with various ribbons on his body. He is also surrounded by the Guardians with Kraglin at his feet and Peter at his head.]

Out of universe though I think this might be a very slight reference to Yondu from the comics, at least in his original form. Initially he was wore a red and yellow outfit and with the style of the comics back in the day shading was done with lots of dark black strokes. It seems if there is a reason this is there it is a reference to that but I admit that is a bit of a stretch.

[image: Yondu from the comics wearing his red and yellow outfit leaping into the air whilst holding his bow] [image: Yondu in the comics wearing a different red and yellow outfit again holding his bow and arrow]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Your hypothesis then is that someone had thoughts about this, but was not clever enough to turn the colors upside down?

Comment: @Allerleirauh I just don’t think it’s a flag, it’s either entirely random or a slight reference but overall coincidental that it looks like a flag. I’ve found nothing explicit on the matter though and no connection between Yondu and Germany: in or out of universe.

Comment: @Allerleirauh You seem to believe that the average viewer will recognize this pattern as the flag of Germany. At least in my experience as a graduate assistant in U.S. political science classrooms, this is incredibly unlikely.

Comment: @indigochild Not that the US is the most educated country in the world when it comes to knowing about other countries outside the US ...